# Detect if .net framework 4.5.X is installed in OS?

Tags: c#, windows, .net-framework-version

What I need to detect if .net framework 4.5.X is installed on the current OS?.

I tried [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17501/Using-managed-code-to-detect-what-NET-Framework-ve?msg=4706288#xx4706288xx) but seems to be limited to framework 4.0 using a non-official update.

Comment: You should not be doing this anymore, starting a .NET 4.x app automatically gets the framework deployed if necessary.  You can still [grovel the registry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you shouldn't.

Comment: if i compile my program targetting .net framework 4.5.1 then i do not should verify that version is installed in the pc because you mean it will automatically get it from the web when i run my program? in any windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just did your googling for you and found the following MSDN article directly referring to your question. Includes examples for version 4.5 and later...

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can look in the registry or simply check in your installed programs.
On Start menu type "appwiz.cpl", then search for .net
You will see all of the .net installed on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Checking the version using >= will enable forward compatibility, 
// however you should always compile your code on newer versions of
// the framework to ensure your app works the same.
private static string CheckFor45DotVersion(int releaseKey)
{
   if (releaseKey >= 393295) {
      return "4.6 or later";
   }
   if ((releaseKey >= 379893)) {
        return "4.5.2 or later";
    }
    if ((releaseKey >= 378675)) {
        return "4.5.1 or later";
    }
    if ((releaseKey >= 378389)) {
        return "4.5 or later";
    }
    // This line should never execute. A non-null release key should mean
    // that 4.5 or later is installed.
    return "No 4.5 or later version detected";
}

private static void Get45or451FromRegistry()
{
    using (RegistryKey ndpKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry32).OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\NET Framework Setup\\NDP\\v4\\Full\\")) {
    if (ndpKey != null && ndpKey.GetValue("Release") != null) {
        Console.WriteLine("Version: " + CheckFor45DotVersion((int) ndpKey.GetValue("Release")));
    }
  else {
     Console.WriteLine("Version 4.5 or later is not detected.");
  } 
}
```

}